# Doing AEM Quick Install once when building a docker image

Tags: docker, aem

I have this docker file:

```
FROM flurdy/oracle-java7

COPY aem-quickstart-5.6.1.jar /aem-quickstart-5.6.1.jar
COPY license.properties /license.properties

RUN java -jar /aem-quickstart-5.6.1.jar -unpack

EXPOSE 4502 4502
ENTRYPOINT ["/crx-quickstart/bin/quickstart"]
```

My intention was to have AEM do all it's startup work with this line:

```
RUN java -jar /aem-quickstart-5.6.1.jar -unpack
```

By that I mean all the unpacking and installing of the AEM bundles.  But all that line does is extract some start/stop scripts.

How can I tell AEM quick start to install all bundles and then shutdown, so I can do that work once at image build time, and have a quick startup time when the image is run.

Comment: How would you do it on a Linux? You will have to do the same thin in a `RUN`

Comment: You run AEM normally by /crx-quickstart/bin/start file and similarly stop it by /crx-quickstart/bin/stop file. -unpack is just for extracting the files and making them runnable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of unpack run aem normally, you can pass a listener-port argument to the startup command and monitor progress, when startup is complete - issue a shutdown.

here is a python based implementation - https://github.com/awadheshv/aem_6-1_docker/blob/master/base/aemInstaller.py